# insert multiple lists from a TXT file into to dictionary?, python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a TXT file with an unknown number of lines.
That I manage to extract to the list and I have this code.

```
dict_items = {"songs": [], "name": [], "length": []}
a = ["Madonna","song_name_1", "3:12"]
b = ["U2","song_name_2","3:14"]
c = ["Prince","song_name_3","4:23"]
```

I want to go through all 13 lines and put them in a dictionary, in this way:

```
{'songs': ['Madonna', 'U2', 'Prince'], 'name': ['song_name_1', 'song_name_2', 'song_name_3'], 'length': ['3:12', '3:14', '4:23']}
```

I'm very confused with this, does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow is expected that show us some code demonstrating what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in each line of your text file, the items are separated by a comma. You can use the pandas [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function to read it and then to convert it to dict with the [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) dataframe method.

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> def strip(s: str) -> str:
        try:
            return s.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.message)
            return s

>>> df = pd.read_csv('my_text_file.txt', names=['songs', 'name', 'length'],
                  converters={'name': strip, 'songs': strip, 'length':strip})
>>> my_dict = df.to_dict(orient='list')
>>> print(my_dict)
{'songs': ['Madonna', 'U2', 'Prince'], 'name': ['song_name_1', 'song_name_2', 'song_name_3'], 'length': ['3:12', '3:14', '4:23']}
```

where the text file content is

```
Madonna, song_name_1, 3:12
U2, song_name_2, 3:14
Prince, song_name_3, 4:23
```

Comment: Hey thanks
Note that this is not the structure I need.
And also there are 13 lines in the file, I have to go through them all

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question. But in all cases the `pd.read_csv` will read all the file content (13 lines or more).
What is structure of your text file?

Comment: The output does not match what I need.
Look at the output I attached above.

Thanks

Comment: Now it should be working fine, I've reversed the columns name and songs and striped the text to remove whitespace.
If it's not the case, please explain the difference between the desired output and what this code outputs. Thanks